# Eulers formula with an infinite series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, euler-mascheroni-constant, eulers-method

Alright so this is a real life problem and not just a homework thing. Ive borrowed money from a family member $16323 \rm dkk$ to be exact. Im borrowing this money for $211$ days and im borrowing it from and account with an interest rate of $0.85$%. My calculations says its : $$16323+16323\cdot0.0085e^{211/365} = 16570.33 \rm dkk$$. But then my mother who is educated in this sort of stuff says that you calculate interest rate of the interest rate, and interest rate on top of that and then an infinite cascade similar to a geometric series. Im saying use Eulers formula to do this since i dont wanna rip anybody off but shes not doing that. How can i caluclate this correctly with the finite series of interest rates?

Comment: Your method is not correct. A quick check shows that if you borrow the same amount for one full year you would only need to repay $16461.75$ which less less than what you have computed for only $211$ days. See my solution for more details.

Comment: What Euler's formula?  He was, quite frankly, too famous to have one single formula, and the formula most commonly tagged with his name deals with complex exponents.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Sure that is a good point. But this is still one of euler's formulae. Hence it would be grammatically correct to consider this euler's formula. In the same way that facebook.com is facebook's domain but not their only domain. In the same way euler's formulae is the set of formulae he's accredited and any member of that set is by definition euler's formula.

Comment: @BenjaminRasmussen The point of my comment was to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let

- $P$=Principal (the amount of loan you took)=$16323$
- $r$=Interest Rate p.a.$=0.85\%=0.0085$
- $n$=Number of days the loan is outstanding = $211$
- $d$=Number of days in a year = $365$

Three methods:

**(1) Daily rest**   (with daily compounding)

Total amount to be repaid*:
$$P\left(1+\frac rd\right)^n=16323\left(1+\frac {0.00085}{365}\right)^{211}=16403.4$$

**(2) Yearly rest**   (interpolated for intra-year period)

Total amount to be repaid*:
$$P\left(1+\frac {rn}d\right)=16323\left(1+\frac {(0.00085)(211)}{365}\right)=16403.2$$

**(3) Continuous Compounding**   (Exponential)

Total amount to be repaid*:
$$P\exp\left(r\left(\frac {n}{d}\right)\right)=16323\;\exp\left((0.00085)\frac{211}{365}\right)=16403.4$$

**(4) Intra-period Compounding**

Total amount to be repaid*:

$$P\left(1+r\right)^{n/d}=16323(1.00085)^{211/365}=16403.1$$
*assuming no repayment of either principal or interest in the interim period

From above the amount to be repaid is approximately the same, i.e. $\approx 16403$.

---

*NB*

If $n=d$, results from methods $(2)$ and $(4)$ are the same.

The notation $\exp(x)$ means the same as $e^x$.

Note that if you chop up a year into $m$ periods, the interest repayment is 
$$P\left[\left(1+\frac rm\right) ^m\right]^\frac nd$$
Setting $m=d$ gives the formula in method $(1)$ above. 
Taking the limit as $m\to \infty$ gives the formula in method $(3)$ above.
$$\lim_{m\to \infty}P\left[\left(1+\frac rm\right) ^m\right]^{n/d}
=P\left[\underbrace{\lim_{m\to \infty}\left(1+\frac rm\right) ^m}_{=e}\right]^{n/d}=Pe^{rn/d}$$

Comment: +1 nice and comprehensive, but your computations are slightly off (the amount to be re-paid should be definitely bigger than the credit amount, though nowadays....) and also there is a typo in your first computation, it should be $\displaystyle P\left(1+\frac rd\right)^n=16323\left(1+\frac {0.00085}{365}\right)^{211}$

Comment: @user190080  Thanks - well spotted! Now corrected.